# JLayer convert mp3 to wav

Tags: java, mp3, wav, jlayer

I am trying to convet mp3 to wav with JLayer, while It seems that it can not set rate.

```
public void convert(String sourceName, String destName,
       ProgressListener progressListener, Decoder.Params decoderParams)
```

Does anyone know how to do it or Are there any other java frameworks like JLayer?

thanks :)

Comment: Can JMF read the MP3 without problem?  For that matter, can JLayer?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don`t know about JMF, but JLayer is working well.Its api is real less.

Comment: *"but JLayer is working well."*  Your question indicates otherwise.  But continue to 'live the dream' it that is what suits you.  *"Its api is real less."*  Real less what?  Bytes to download?  I doubt it, since the `mp3plugin.jar` is all that is needed to add MP3 support to JavaSound.  --  But you seem unwilling to follow my leads or answer my questions, so.. good luck with it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry I really haven't used JMF before. what I want now is just convert mp3 to wav and I need not to play it.

Comment: My question about whether JMF could 'play' the MP3 related directly to the ability of the `mp3plugin.jar` to perform the task you want to achieve.  I am not going to ask you again.  ***Answer*** my question from the first comment or ..deal with it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Converter c=new Converter();
c.convert("mysong.mp3","mysong.wav");
```